# How can we find the cross of a line passing through a vector and a point with a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, vector-spaces

We have three unit vectors ($A$, $B$, $C$), which are perpendicular to each other.

How can we find the cross point of the blue line passing through the point $P$ with plane $AB$? The line has an angle of $d$ with the vector $C$.

The purpose is to find the projection of the point Q on vectors $A$ and $B$ ($Q_a$ and $Q_b$) if we can go through a shortcut.

[image]

Comment: who would be $Q$?

Comment: @astro a point on the $AB$ plane.

Comment: Hint: consider the orthogonal distance from $P$ to your $C$ axis (BTW, I _highly_ recommend relabeling those $x$, $y$, and $z$!). That, along with the $z$ coordinate of $P$ and your angle, will let you determine the point $R$ of intersection of that line with the $z$ axis (why?) — and then determining the intersection of the line through $R$ and $P$ with the $xy$ plane is a simple linear projection.

Comment: Is this in dimension 3? Even more, is this $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @astro yes, it is in 3D. Consider it as $x,y,z$. The purpose is to find $Q$ on the $xy$ plane, and ultimately finding $x$ and $y$ for the intersection of line blue and $xy$ plane.

Comment: Then it is just some hardwork to get it all done with explicit equations. Good Luck!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki your hint looks straightforward. Could you please give me a sub-hint, how to get the intersection $R$? we have two vectors, a point, and angle. How do you solve this triangle $OPR$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have unit basis vector $\hat{c}$ perpendicular to the plane you wish to project point $\vec{v}$ to, use
$$\vec{v}^\prime = \vec{v} - \hat{c} \left( \hat{c} \cdot \vec{v} \right)$$

In this case, the projection is not perpendicular, but a right circular cone with aperture $2 d$ with radius $\lVert\vec{P} - \hat{c} \cdot \vec{P} \rVert$ where it intersects $\vec{P}$.

Let's say we have two points on the cone, $\vec{p}_0 = ( a_0 , b_0 , c_0 )$ and $\vec{p}_1 = \vec{P} = ( a_1 , b_1 , c_1 )$.  If the two points are both on the blue line in OP's picture, they are on the same generatrix, and
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{a_0}{b_0} = \frac{a_1}{b_1}, & b_0 \ne 0, ~ b_1 \ne 0 \\
\frac{b_0}{a_0} = \frac{b_1}{a_1}, & a_0 \ne 0, ~ a_1 \ne 0 \\
\end{cases} \quad \iff \quad a_0 b_1 = b_0 a_1$$
If we consider the situation perpendicular to the $C$ axis, we have
$$\tan d = \frac{r_0 - r_1}{c_1 - c_0} \quad \iff \quad r_0 = r_1 + (c_1 - c_0) \tan d$$
(the signs determined by the orientation of the cone), where
$$r_0 = \sqrt{x_0^2 + y_0^2}, ~ r_1 = \sqrt{x_1^2 + y_1^2}$$
In other words, in the $A B C$ coordinate system, the projected point $\vec{p}_0$ on the $A B$ plane ($c_0 = 0$) is
$$\vec{p}_0 = \left [ \begin{matrix} a_1 + c_1 \tan d \\ b_1 + c_1 \tan d \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right ]$$

Let's say we have a coordinate system with origin at $\vec{o} = ( x_o , y_o , z_o )$, unit $A$ axis vector $\vec{a} = ( x_A , y_A , z_A )$, unit $B$ axis vector $\vec{b} = ( x_B , y_B , z_B )$, and unit $C$ axis vector $\vec{c} = ( x_C , y_C , z_C )$, the three vectors perpendicular and having lengths 1 in the $A B C$ coordinate system; i.e., forming an orthogonal basis.  In this coordinate system, let's say $\vec{P} = ( x_P , y_P , z_P )$.  Then, the $A B C$ coordinate system coordinates are
$$\begin{cases}
a_1 = x_A ( x_P - x_o ) + y_A ( y_P - y_o ) + z_A ( z_P - z_o ) \\
b_1 = x_B ( x_P - x_o ) + y_B ( y_P - y_o ) + z_B ( z_P - z_o ) \\
c_1 = x_C ( x_P - x_o ) + y_C ( y_P - y_o ) + z_C ( z_P - z_o ) \\
\end{cases}$$

You can therefore projecting point $(x_P , y_P , z_P)$ to the $A B$ plane at $(a, b)$ using
$$\begin{aligned}
x_\Delta &= x_P - x_o \\
y_\Delta &= y_P - y_o \\
z_\Delta &= z_P - z_o \\
a_1 &= x_A x_\Delta + y_A y_\Delta + z_A z_\Delta \\
b_1 &= x_B x_\Delta + y_B y_\Delta + z_B z_\Delta \\
c_1 &= x_C x_\Delta + y_C y_\Delta + z_C z_\Delta \\
a &= a_1 + c_1 \tan d \\
b &= b_1 + c_1 \tan d \\
\end{aligned}$$

For a large number of points $(x_P , y_P , z_P)$, you can use
$$\begin{cases}
a = A_X x_P + A_Y y_P + A_Z z_P - A_0 \\
b = B_X x_P + B_Y y_P + B_Z z_P - B_0 \\
\end{cases}$$
where the constants do not depend on $x_P$, $y_P$, or $z_P$, so you can precalculate them:
$$\begin{aligned}
t_d &= \tan d \\
A_X &= x_A + t_d x_C \\
A_Y &= y_A + t_d y_C \\
A_Z &= z_A + t_d z_C \\
A_0 &= x_o A_X + y_o A_Y + z_o A_Z \\
B_X &= x_B + t_d x_C \\
B_Y &= y_B + t_d y_C \\
B_Z &= z_B + t_d z_C \\
B_0 &= x_o B_X + y_o B_Y + z_o B_Z \\
\end{aligned}$$

---

In case you happen to need the intersections in the original coordinates (only):

The conversion from $A B C$ coordinates to $x y z$ coordinates is
$$\begin{cases}
x = x_o + a x_A + b x_B + c x_C \\
y = y_o + a y_A + b y_B + c y_C \\
z = z_o + a z_A + b z_B + c z_C \\
\end{cases}$$
In the original coordinate system, the projected point is at $(x, y, z)$:
$$\begin{aligned}
x_\Delta &= x_P - x_o \\
y_\Delta &= y_P - y_o \\
z_\Delta &= z_P - z_o \\
a_1 &= x_A x_\Delta + y_A y_\Delta + z_A z_\Delta \\
b_1 &= x_B x_\Delta + y_B y_\Delta + z_B z_\Delta \\
c_1 &= x_C x_\Delta + y_C y_\Delta + z_C z_\Delta \\
a_0 &= a_1 + c_1 \tan d \\
b_0 &= b_1 + c_1 \tan d \\
x &= x_o + a_0 x_A + b_0 x_B \\
y &= y_o + a_0 y_A + b_0 y_B \\
z &= z_o + a_0 z_A + b_0 z_B \\
\end{aligned}$$

If you have a lot of points to project, you can use
$$\begin{cases}
x = X_X x_P + X_Y y_P + X_Z z_P - X_0 \\
y = Y_X x_P + Y_Y y_P + Y_Z z_P - Y_0 \\
z = Z_x x_P + Z_y y_P + Z_Z z_P - Z_0 \\
\end{cases}$$
where the constants do not depend on $x_P$, $y_P$, or $z_P$:
$$\begin{aligned}
t_d &= \tan d \\
X_X &= x_A^2 + x_B^2 + t_d x_C (x_A + x_B) \\
X_Y &= x_A y_A + x_B y_B + t_d y_C (x_A + x_B) \\
X_Z &= x_A z_A + x_B z_B + t_d z_C (x_A + x_B) \\
X_0 &= x_o X_X + y_o X_Y + z_o X_Z - x_o \\
Y_X &= x_A y_A + x_B y_B + t_d x_C (y_A + y_B) \\
Y_Y &= y_A^2 + y_B^2 + t_d y_C (y_A + y_B) \\
Y_Z &= y_A z_A + y_B z_B + t_d z_C (y_A + y_B) \\
Y_0 &= x_o Y_X + y_o Y_Y + z_o Z_Z - y_o \\
Z_X &= z_A x_A + z_B x_B + t_d x_C ( z_A + z_B ) \\
Z_Y &= z_A y_A + z_B y_B + t_d y_C ( z_A + z_B ) \\
Z_Z &= z_A^2 + z_B^2 + t_d z_C ( z_A + z_B ) \\
Z_0 &= x_o Z_X + y_o Z_Y + z_o Z_Z - z_o \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: it was an incredible answer. I enjoyed reading every line of it!